# How randomly to choose buttons

Tags: java, android

I have a UI, like this

[image: UI]

What I want is to choose randomly 3 of them and change their texts. Thank you.

UPD1:
What ive tried:

```
ArrayList<Button> _btnList = new ArrayList<Button>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 16; ++i) {
        _btnList.add(btn1);
    }
```

here I stucked, how to add all that buttons inside.

upd2: done, really not to answer and put minuses make the mind to work

Comment: It seems as if you're new to java. Check out some code samples of random generation in java.

Comment: I updated where I stucked. Sorry if you think it was stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, on onCreate(), create a new ArrayList and add all the buttons to it.

Then just generate 3 random ints between 0 and 15 (16*Math.Random casted to int will do the trick), check if some of them repeat, if they do change them so you get 3 different numbers, get the buttons at array.get(random) and change their texts.

Comment: I did not put ANY runnable code on purpose. I told what to do, not how to do it. He can learn from this ;-)

Comment: I did it in different way, using shuffle. In my case I dont need random to be used. Thanks for hint about Arraylist of buttons.